# What is the number of $6$ digit positive integers whose sum of the digits is at least $52$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, analytic-combinatorics

> What is the number of $6$ digit positive integers whose sum of the digits is at least $52$?

**My kind of approach was**:

I thought to use Multinomial Theorem concept here.

So my primary  aim was to find the coefficient of $x^{52}$in {followed by $x^{53}$ and $x^{54}$[$54$ will be highest because $6\cdot 9=54$]}
$$(x^{1}+x^{2}+x^{3}+\ldots+x^{9})^{6};$$
$=\text{finding coefficient  of }  x^{52 }  \text{ from }  x^{6}\cdot (1-x^{9})^{6}\cdot (1-x)^{-6}$
$=\text{this is equivalent to finding coefficient of } x^{46 } \text{ from }  (1-x^{9})^{6}\cdot (1-x)^{-6}$

$=(1-x^{9}+x^{18}-x^{27}+x^{36}-x^{45})\cdot (1-x)^{-6}$[rest term will be a waste]

This leads to:
$\binom{51}{46}-\binom{42}{37}+\binom{33}{28}-\binom{24}{19}+\binom{15}{10}-\binom{6}{1}$

But it is a wrong answer.  How to use Multinomial correctly?

Comment: It is hard to evaluate work that you have not shown.  Please edit your question to show what you did.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig please check

Comment: Don’t forget to multiply each term with $6\choose k$, arising from $(1-x^9)^6$.

Comment: I multiplied ....The result I am talking about is the final one..wait I am showing the step

Comment: @Tavish check now

Comment: Your expansion of $(1-x^9)^6$ is wrong. You also need to multiply with the respective binomial coefficients, e.g. $6\choose 2$ with $x^{18}$.

Comment: @Tavish can u pls show me the expansion?

Comment: @Integralcalculus $$(1-x^9)^6 = \sum_{i=0}^6 {6\choose i} (-x^9)^i $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $6\cdot 9=54$ so having 52 is hard - it requires very high digits.

You can think of it as starting with 999999 (sum=54) and then removing 2. You can either do it in two places (turning two 9 into 8) or in one place (turn one 9 into 7).
The number of options is
$${6 \choose 2}+6$$
To get 53 you need to remove only 1 (6 options) and to get 54 you have one the above- mentioned options.

To conclude, the number of 6 digit integers with sum of at least 52 is
$${6 \choose 2}+6+6+1$$

Comment: thanks for the answer. But my question is:Why I am not getting the result using Multinomial

Answer (score 1):

You should have:
$$[x^{52}](1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^9)^6=[x^{52}]\left(\frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x}\right)^6=\\
[x^{52}](1-x^{10})^6\cdot (1-x)^{-6}=\\
[x^{52}]\sum_{i=0}^6 {6\choose i}(-x^{10})^i\cdot \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}{-6\choose j}(-x)^j=\\
[x^{52}]\sum_{i=0}^6 {6\choose i}(-x^{10})^i\cdot \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}{6+j-1\choose j}x^j=\\
\small{57\choose 52}-{6\choose 1}{47\choose 42}+{6\choose 2}{37\choose 32}-{6\choose 3}{27\choose 22}+{6\choose 4}{17\choose 12}-{6\choose 5}{7\choose 2}=21$$
Wolfram [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binom%2857%2C52%29-binom%286%2C1%29*binom%2847%2C42%29%2Bbinom%286%2C2%29*binom%2837%2C32%29-binom%286%2C3%29*binom%2827%2C22%29%2Bbinom%286%2C4%29*binom%2817%2C12%29-binom%286%2C5%29*binom%287%2C2%29).

Indeed, to have the sum of $52$, the digits should be $799999$ or $889999$:
$${6\choose 1}+\frac{6!}{2!4!}=21.$$